# UTC DateTime problems

Tags: ajax, datetime, browser, offset, utc

I currently store all dateTimes in the DB as UTC dates. Each users time zone offset is also stored in the DB. When I retrieve a Date it is converted back to their local date using this offset.

The problem occurs when I retrieve a date using an ajax call. The date (which is already converted using the offset) is, I think, returned as a Java Date object. The browser then decides to mess with my Date adding the clients computers time zone offset to the Date object. This is causing dates to be a day ahead of what they should be if the time component is more than 11.59am.

The only solution I can come up with is to pass them as strings in which case this of course wouldn't happen. This is a laaaast resort for me though and I would love to find a better solution or workaround for this problem.

Comment: can we see some of the of AJAX call?

Answer (score 2):

Your browser is not messing with the dates given that browsers don't have a native date transfer variable. You have something else that is doing that. How are you sending your dates in ajax? Json? Json will only send numbers or strings. XML will only send strings.

Something is converting your sent date into a javascript date object, find out what it is.

Comment: It is a third party component, the dates are presented in a Telerik Grid which is probably the culprit. Thanks for your fast reply by the way. I'm still not sure what to do with this problem and Telerik support have been usually unhelpful.

Comment: Can you send the dates as unix timestamps (integers)? Those are always UTC and are very easy to convert. Instead of "When I retrieve a Date it is converted back to their local date using this offset." do the conversion at the last possible moment - right before display.

Comment: I'm using asp.Net MVC. I convert them in the controller right before returning the view.

Comment: Let javascript act as the view. (A view in asp is the model to javascript.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The view is strongly typed to the Model. The grid gets its data from the Model.

Comment: I was assuming you have some javascript programming. That programming would be the model (in javascript). The programming arrives at the browser by being sent from the asp view.